# Image rotate pagination question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

trying to get the pagination inside the main area display to look a little better. Where it has the pagination, i would like the active states to be formatted to fit perfectly inside the appropriate boxes without the numbers showing but having some difficulties.

you can view the image rotate pagination issue here:
http://obliqueinteractive.com/demo/oblique/

Here is the code im working with for the pagination:

HTML

```
<div class="paging">
    <a href="#" rel="1">1</a>
    <a href="#" rel="2">2</a>
    <a href="#" rel="3">3</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.paging {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px; 
 left: 372px;
 width: 189px; 
 height:41px;
 z-index: 100; /*--Assures the paging stays on the top layer--*/
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 40px;
 background: url(../images/paging_bg2.png) no-repeat;
 display: none; /*--Hidden by default, will be later shown with jQuery--*/
}
.paging a {
 padding: 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;

}
.paging a.active {
 background-image: url(../images/active.png) ;
 width:12px;
 height:11px;
}
.paging a:hover {
 background-image: url(../images/active.png) ;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work? It's not clear from your link.

Comment: i would like to get rid of the number values and have a small blue circle as the hover and active states

Answer (score 1):

> .paging a {
>   background-repeat:no-repeat;
>   background-position: x-offset
>   y-offset; }

change offsets in pixels to fit Your layout
and change content of  to:

> $nbsp;